# Python count everytime a string is found in another string

Tags: python

I'm trying to enumerate the time the program finds a specific string in a longer text but I'm stuck, the program shows the length of the response string instead of the times `ultrias` is present in response. Here's the code:

```
ultrias = "am 17"
response = "Hi i am 17, did you know I am 17"
num = 0
for ultrias in response:
    num += 1
print (num)
```

Comment: Do you need to count _overlapping_ occurrences ? Say how many time is  `171` in `17171` ? One or two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python strings have a built-in `str.count()` method that can do that:

```
ultrias = "am 17"
response = "Hi i am 17, did you know I am 17"
print(response.count(ultrias))
```

**output**

```
2
```

If you aren't permitted to use the `str.count()` method, you *could* do something like this:

```
ultrias = "am 17"
response = "Hi i am 17, did you know I am 17"

count = 0
data = response[:]
while True:
    start = data.find(ultrias)
    if start < 0:
        break
    data = data[start + len(ultrias):]
    count += 1
print(count)
```

But I wouldn't recommend it.

Neither of these algorithms handle overlapping matches, but the second example can be easily modified to do that:

```
count = 0
data = response[:]
while True:
    start = data.find(ultrias)
    if start < 0:
        break
    data = data[start + 1:]
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered with a few different ways to achieve your requirement, however, none explained why the output of your code is the length of the input string.

`for` loops have a loop variable that is assigned values from the object that is being iterated over. In the case of the object being a string, the for loop will iterate in order over each character in the string, assigning the character to the loop variable  e.g.

```
>>> for i in "Hi there":
...     print i
... 
H
i

t
h
e
r
e
```

So you can see that `i` is assigned in turn a character from the string "Hi there". The same thing is happening in your code: `ultrias` is the loop variable and is being assigned consecutive characters from the string `"Hi i am 17, did you know I am 17"`.

```
ultrias = "am 17"
response = "Hi i am 17, did you know I am 17"
num = 0
for ultrias in response:
    print(ultrias)
    num += 1
print (num)
```

The output will be:

```
H
i

i

a
m

1
7
.
.
.

3
```

Also note that the value of `ultrias` after the loop has terminated is the last value assigned it by the loop - not `"am 17"` but `"7"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
>>> ultrias = "am 17"
>>> response = "Hi i am 17, did you know I am 17"
>>> response.count(ultrias)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string.count(string) to get what you need.

```
>>> find = "am 17"
>>> string = "Hi I am 17, did you know I am 17"
>>> string.count(find)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Through `re` module.

```
>>> ultrias = "am 17"
>>> response = "Hi i am 17, did you know I am 17"
>>> print(len(re.findall(ultrias, response)))
2
```